# Why is this object not recognized?

Tags: java, arraylist, box2d

I am trying to implement this solution to my problem from this answer: [libGDX Box2D: How to destroy body after collision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051102/libgdx-box2d-how-to-destroy-body-after-collision)
But nothing is happening but the method executes and shows no errors. This means that the kugelbody (circle) is not inserted into the array list. (I think)

I need the circlebody to be deleted on collision with a square. The square is saved in an arraylist with other squares.

```
 world.setContactListener(new ContactListener() {
        @Override
        public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
            Fixture fixtureA = contact.getFixtureA();
            Fixture fixtureB = contact.getFixtureB();

           //ist a oder b ein quadrat?
            boolean isSquareA = fixtureA != null && squareBodies.contains(fixtureA.getBody());
            boolean isSquareB = fixtureB != null && squareBodies.contains(fixtureB.getBody());

            if (isSquareA || isSquareB) {
                // Kollision mit einem Quadrat
                Body ballBody = isSquareA ? fixtureB.getBody() : fixtureA.getBody();
                int squareIndex = isSquareA ? squareBodies.indexOf(fixtureA.getBody()) : squareBodies.indexOf(fixtureB.getBody());

                // Todo kontostandplus einsatz * multipklikrator
                //todo evtl 0.2 | 0.5 |1.2 |2 |10 |2 |1.2 |0.5 |0.2
                long []abc = {(long) 0.2, (long) 0.5, (long) 1.2,2,10};
                switch (squareIndex) {
                   (...) }
                    delkugel.add(ballBody);
            }
        }
```

The render method:

```
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    b2dr.render(world, b2dcam.combined);
 
    if (delkugel.size() > 0) { delkugel.clear();}

    stage.act();
    stage.draw();
}
```

The method of the Ballgeneration:

```
private void dropBall(int posX){
    final BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
    FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();

    bdef.position.set(posX / PPM, 790 / PPM);
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;

    // Randomly drop ball
    final Body body = world.createBody(bdef);
    CircleShape cshape = new CircleShape();
    cshape.setRadius(13 / PPM);
    fdef.shape = cshape;
    fdef.filter.categoryBits = Box2dVars.BIT_BALL;
    fdef.filter.maskBits = Box2dVars.BIT_WALLS | Box2dVars.BIT_PEG;
    fdef.restitution = 0.7f;
    fdef.density = 0.9f;
    fdef.friction = 0.1f;
    body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData("ball");

    Timer.schedule(new Timer.Task() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (body != null && world != null && world.getBodyCount() > 0) {
                world.destroyBody(body);
            }
        }
    }, 10);

}
```

And the method of the squaregeneration:

```
         int squareSize = 20;
    for (int i = 10; i < 100; i = i + 10) {
        BodyDef bdef;
        FixtureDef fdef;
PolygonShape shape;

        bdef = new BodyDef();
        fdef = new FixtureDef();
        shape = new PolygonShape();
        bdef.position.set((Game.WIDTH * i / PPM) / PPM, (150 + 10) / PPM);
        bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
        Body body = world.createBody(bdef);


        shape.setAsBox(squareSize / PPM, squareSize / PPM);

        fdef.shape = shape;
        fdef.filter.categoryBits = Box2dVars.BIT_WALLS;
        fdef.filter.maskBits = Box2dVars.BIT_BALL;
        body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData("wall");

        squareBodies.add(body);
    }
}
```